# Management expects full participation in holiday nonsense video

Tags: morale

Management expects every department to pick a song and participate in a song and dance video to be shown company-wide (think https://youtu.be/X0v_InsGdSE ). Everyone is "expected" to participate, though many find it demeaning. How do we opt out without being perceived as non team players?

Comment: And will your management does one for themselves ? Surely that would be fun ...

Comment: Offer to participate by running the camera or helping to edit or something else other than performing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm going to answer in a somewhat different direction. If you don't want to do this, assert confidently that you are not going to participate. If this causes backlash and insistence on you participating, then keep in mind the following.

Your company is trying to force you to do an activity that is:

- Not related to your job at all
- Not (strongly*) related to the company's goal or mission
- Clearly making you uncomfortable
- And because you (and perhaps others) are being forced into doing it despite all this, completely missing it's only potentially valid point of being "fun" or "teambuilding", since it clearly isn't to you.

This is not about "being a teamplayer" at all. This is about the company trying to coerce you into a pointless activity that makes you uncomfortable while trying to pretend they're doing "something fun".

It is a sign of a strongly dysfunctional organization, and you should start looking for a new job. Forcing people to do things that make them uncomfortable "because it'll be fun" is not okay.

(And while you're searching for a new job, calling in sick is probably the best way to get out of this specific event)

*this might be meant as a cute marketing stunt, in which case there's some connection to the goal of the company, but still no reason at all to force anyone into participating.

Comment: This is the answer, with the exception of taking a sick day. I'm a great team player in work projects but I'm not employed to sing and dance. If you want me to do such performances, you'd need to pay me a hell of a lot more (and won't get a good return of investment). However, I've never had an issue with opting out of silly activities. Delivering quality work and being good at team work is usually more important and if it isn't it's the wrong job for me.

Comment: good except for 'not related to the company's goal or mission" - often management is doing this either as a marketing thing to the customers (and customers are part of the mission, right?) or as a teambuilding thing aimed at employee comradery or the like, again part of the mission of most companies. They're not entering Companies Have Talent - there is a business reason for the activity .

Comment: @KateGregory It's horrible teambuilding though, as it's making employees uncomfortable. And if they're doing it for the customers, it would work just as well without forcing anyone, so even there it's a bad idea to use force.

Comment: @Erik no argument. Some employees are loving it and some are dreading it (many answers here assume ALL employees find it demeaning and I bet that's not correct) so a natural thing to do would be to make it optional. Another natural thing to do is make it clear to everyone what the company gains from making a good video. I'm not saying this firm has great management and communication because they clearly don't. I'm just challenging the flat-out statement that making the video has nothing to do with company goals and missions. I'm sure the intention is for it to support those goals and mission.

Comment: @KateGregory I agree there, so 've added a footnote to the answer.

Comment: I've never seen this sort of video (whether it's a "cute marketing stunt" or otherwise) where I, as the viewer, didn't cringe for at least half of it and genuinely feel sorry for the people who were required to appear in it.

Answer (score 12):

You have two choices:

- do it, in a nondemeaning way. You don't have to wear a silly costume, film in a silly location, etc. If you have a choice of music you can choose something you're ok with. Someone may "tut" that you didn't make a fool of yourself, but you participated.
- don't do it. Either by "not getting around to it" because you've "got a lot on your plate this week" or by replying to the reminders saying you're not going to do it. Either may cause someone to feel you're not a team player.

These videos are rarely designed to be demeaning. They are supposed to be fun, and to demonstrate a more personal side to your coworkers or customers. I've done my share, and they can be pleasant. (They've always been optional and the recording is just of yourself, and gets cut into a larger montage. The department-by-department approach here makes things trickier.) I'm not going to put on a crazy wig or dance on my desk. I don't think you have to either.

Answer (score 10):

Just suck it up and do it.

Things like this matter more than you would think, and you might actually have fun.  Management remembers who was and was not a team player.

Not saying its fair, just telling you how it is. ( at least in the US )

Comment: I used to work at a company that did these very year.  They were *HORRIBLE*.  However, the owner expected full participation.  Wasn't worth fighting.

Answer (score 7):

If you can't avoid it, then someone has to be film-crew, animal-wrangler, key-grip etc.  Be creative and think up some very important reason why you can't be on the action side of the camera.

Answer (score 4):

I'd take a sick day - hey, the very thought of participating in the video makes me sick. Or I'd take a personal day - hey, my pet rock is feeling neglected :)

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest a different approach to the situation. Such videos also need much more than "actors in them". They need someone:

- to help setting up some decorations in the location where it's filmed
- to go pick up the costumes or hats or whatever
- to go pick up the camera from the manager's brother who agreed to lend it for a few days
- to actually film the thing
- to actually add the music / edit the video / publish it etc.
- to do other stuff that I can't think of right now

There's a lot of stuff that needs to be done so that such a video is a "successfull" one.

If you don't want to risk being seen as "not a team player", then you can participate in such a video without being an "actor". Just suggest it to your manager or whoever is responsible for it.

---

As a side-note / personal comment: I too think such videos are kind of a waste of time and frankly quite pathetic. Managers / executives simply want to portray an image of "look how fun we are and what a great place to work this is", but it's simply fake and everyone sees through it... or they should.

Answer (score 1):

I'm kinda surprised that no one mentioned this yet, but compelling people to participate in any "holiday celebration" is assuming that it is a holiday for everyone. Basically not everyone celebrates these holidays and forcing people to participate, in what could be seen as religious holidays, could be an HR nightmare.

Even if this isn't your reason, you could drop that bug in someone's ear and get the whole thing called off.

"You know I like the holidays as much as anyone, but have you considered..."